# Seamless onClick animated <div>s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a portfolio website for a photographer. The idea is to have 3 main sections, animated on click. When you click on any of those it will take about 80% space revealing itself and pushing others to the side(s). They will be packed with content like albums, text, images etc. It has to be seamless transitions between those 3 and any clickable item inside. that's the question itself: how do i achieve that, i suppose it has to be JS, maybe there is ready framework for that feature? Check out pic below for better understanding

[image]

Comment: Where is your markup? Show some effort.

Comment: It's simple, i just need an answer is there a ready framework for that so i don't reinvent the wheel, or if not what technology to use. The only reason why I'm asking in here and not in google.com is that i had no luck to find proper info there. I'll keep lurking anyway and WHEN i find the solution i will post it here so the next person need it don't have to waste hours for it. Simply as that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as the basis to fit it to you use-case. Works on hover on any section.

Snippet:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif; }
.parent {
  width: 100vw; height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: columns;
}
.parent > div { 
  background-color: #ddd; text-align: center; padding: 12px 8px;
  flex: 1 1 10%;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
.parent > div:hover {
  flex: 1 1 80%;
}
.parent > div:first-child { background-color: #d33; }
.parent > div:last-child { background-color: #33d; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped, i do more understand how it can be done now.